# listview height jquery-mobile 1.4

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile-listview

Which css class I have to change to properly adjust the height of a li-element in the new  version of jquery-mobile (1.4 version)?

[image: listview]

I am adding the li-elements dynamically through jquery-tmpl:

```
<script id="cases" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">    
<li class="ui-li-has-thumb"><a href="#"><img src="./icons/thumb.svg" class="ui-li-thumb"><b>${title}</b></a></li>
      </script>
```

best

M

update:

found the responsible classes in the css file:

```
.ui-listview > .ui-li-has-thumb > .ui-btn, .ui-listview > 
.ui-li-static.ui-li-has-thumb {
min-height: 1.625em;
padding-left: 6.25em; }
```